# JUnit, H2, JaxRS, drop in-memory database between test methods

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, jersey, jax-rs

How do I drop or delete or rollback or disconnect from my H2 database between test methods?

Here is a bit of my hibernate test configuration:

```
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM './h2-ext/add_to_date.sql'
    </property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

I have a base class that I'm inheriting all my tests from:

```
public abstract class BaseTest {

    @After
    public void drop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("!!!!!! DROP !!!!!!&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        // this seems to do nothing
        //org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.deleteRecursive("mem:test", true);
        //org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.deleteRecursive("NoTellingwhatThisdoes", true);

        // the schema does not get recreated, it seems
        //Session sess = DB.sf.openSession();
        //sess.createSQLQuery("DROP ALL OBJECTS;").executeUpdate();

        // org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot truncate "PUBLIC.FOO";
        //Session sess = DB.sf.openSession();
        //sess.createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE FOO;").executeUpdate();
        //sess.createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE BAR;").executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

It seems that there should be a simple way to execute an integration test like this?

Maybe I can use some Transactional annotation of some sort? But, I would like to know how to do this with relatively vanilla jersey+JUnit.

Jersey is 2.12, Java 1.7, H2 is 1.4.181, JUnit is 4.11.

Versions are negotiable.

Comment: Arquillian has a persistence extension that may be of interest to you.  http://arquillian.org/modules/persistence-extension/

Comment: What happens if you execute the SQL statement `shutdown`? It's an in-memory database, I think that should clear it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a SQL file which handles the (re-)initialization. With such a file you might use:

```
import org.h2.tools.RunScript;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;  // get your DataSource somehow

@Before
public void setup() {
    RunScript.execute(dataSource.getConnection(), new FileReader("src/test/resources/testdb/data.sql");
    ...
```

and the database in in shape again for every test.

Don't run tests in parallel though.

A different - and maybe better approach:

- Write the tests so that the state of the database does not matter and each test can run in parallel with others and itself. Then you can use these tests for load tests.